# Find/Replace with changing value?

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have nearly a thousand lines that I want to edit with Find/Replace in Notepad++.  Each line starts with

```
<option value="43979">
```

Except the number changes, each line.  How can I remove that entire segment with Find/Replace, to account for the changing number section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for `<option value="[0-9]+">` (and replace with nothing).